# iOS wrong orientation when using front camera on UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, exif

I'm using `UIImagePickerController` to snap an image and uploading it to server.

When taking a photo in the front camera, the height/width get reversed somewhere.

The image is displayed correctly later, but height and width are reversed (and I'm using them for the UIImageView autolayout constraint)

The thing is - that when looking at `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` of front and back camera images - the EXIF and the rest of the metadata is the same (resolution is smaller but the height/width ratio is the same)

Any ideas what is the difference?

Comment: Apple images are always landscape left with EXIF and the orientation is specified in the EXIF.

Comment: So why are the images turn out different?

Comment: @zaph - You are right, see my answer for what happened. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple images are always landscape left with EXIF and the orientation is specified in the EXIF.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so @zaph comment is correct, apparently back camera images are "reversed" as well - the upload code in the server (Codeigniter PHP) ignored the EXIF.

The problem surfaced only due to front camera low resolution...